# Export photoshop layer with blending option: screen applied on it

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, blending

I was trying to export the photoshop layer as save for web that has a blending option screen set to it which makes it lighter.

[image]

But when I hide other layers and try to export that pink overlay that has screen set as blending option it gives me the darker version of it that is below.

[image]

I think its exporting it with normal blending option.

Comment: You have to save each persons photo with this pink graidnet and its blend mode or try to cope without a blend mode

Answer (score 5):

**Screen** blending mode is only a Photoshop mode, so when you export it to (JPG, PNG, etc) it flattens the layers and saves how it thinks it should. Blending modes do not exist for these files.

Try saving your photo as part of your image export. If you need to use the same Gradient over several images, just save the process as an **action** and let the action do all the hard work of repeating the process.

Comment: Done it ... Still same issue

Comment: Actually I'm a web programmer and need this overlay image as a transparent graphic so I can use it in my code and it overlays to the image user upload.

Comment: CSS has blend modes as well; screen is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Well I didn't find the answer of my question and may be its not possible...

But one possibility is this that we can create same effect without using the blending options.

[image]

Its not 100% like the one with blending option but this will do :)

Comment: have you tried converting it into a smart object ?

Comment: Yes But not getting the results I wanted